# get the content as well tags of the editable area from iframe editable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, iframe

i have created a small editor where i have done a few commands as an example font formatting and
 alignment etc so it is working fine in the browsers but i want to export the data which is written
 in the editable area while i tried to fetch the data inside the editable iframe but it gives me an error.
**error message: Uncaught ReferenceError: innerDoc is not defined**

the following code is written

> <html><head><title></title>
>   <script>
>   function iFrameOn() {
> richTextField.document.designMode = 'On';
>   }
>   function export_Data() {
>   var n = document.getElementById("richTextField");
>   var innerdoc = n.contentDocument || n.contentWindow.document;
>   var input = innerDoc.getElementsByTagName('body').text;
>   var zip = new JSZip();
>   zip.add("hello1.html", ""+input);
>   zip.add("hello2.js", "this is just a simple file");
>   content = zip.generate();
>   location.href="data:application/zip;base64," + content;
>   </script>
>   </head>
>   <body>
>   <iframe name="richTextField" id="richTextField" class="form-control" style="height:100%; word-wrap:break-word;">
>   <button onclick="export_Data()" name="export">Export information</button>
>   </body>
>   </html>

Please Help me out this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is on the same domain, try this. It won't let you access iframe contents if the iframe is of a different origin than the window that you are viewing.

```
var n = document.getElementById("richTextField");
var innerdoc  = n.contentDocument.body.innerHTML;
```

Comment: if i want to retrieve full contents with its tag....? it is some how working. this will help me well i have tried in different ways this is some how it will help me thanks